# Example of compact non-Hausdorff space that fails to be locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Can you give an example of a compact non-Hausdorff space with a point which has no local base formed by compact neighborhoods?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one-point compactification of the rationals is such a space: $X = \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$ , where neighbourhoods of rational $x$ are the usual ones (inherited from $\mathbb{R}$) and neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are of the form $\{\infty\} \cup \mathbb{Q}\setminus K$, where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (in the usual topology).

All rational points still don't have a base of compact neighbourhoods (every open interval intersected with the rationals contain sequences of rationals converging to an irrational (in the  reals) so that sequential compactness fails), while $X$ is compact by construction, but not Hausdorff (as the one-point compactification of a space $Y$ is Hausdorff iff $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff).

So this is actually a family of examples: one-point compactifications of non-locally compact spaces $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$, defined in the same way in general: the set $\alpha X = X \cup \{\infty\}$ with topology 
$$\mathcal{T}_X \cup \{ (X\setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}: \text{ with } K \subseteq X \text{ closed and compact }\}$$.

$\alpha X$ is always compact (same proof as for locally compact spaces), $X$ is dense in $\alpha X$ and $x \rightarrow x$ is an open embedding  of $X$ into $\alpha X$. $\alpha X$ is Hausdorff iff $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.
(see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension), e.g.). It's because of the last property that it's usually only introduced (in books) for the locally compact case. (as compact Hausdorff spaces have nicer properties than compact and $T_1$ spaces).

Comment: I know that we can do one-point compactification for locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Is it possible to do that for general topological spaces?

Comment: @OscarLIU I expanded it a bit.

Comment: I got that. Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The one point compactification of the rationals (and any power thereof) is an example: [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B~%24T_2%24%2B~Locally%20Compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%7E%24T_2%24%2B%7ELocally%20Compact)

Comment: Henno Brandsma gave this answer already in 2017.

Comment: He didn't point out that the square is also an example, nor provided a resource to look up such things, so I thought this answer might help readers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider and infinite topological space $X$ with $\tau$ being the cofinite topology.

I claim $(X,\tau)$ is compact and non-Hausdorff.

First for Non-Hausdorff, suppose it is. Then let $x \neq y \in X$ and $U_x,U_y \in \tau$ be disjoint. Then we have

$$X \setminus U_x = \{x_1,...,x_m\}$$

and

$$X \setminus U_y = \{y_1,...,y_n\}.$$

where $x_i \neq y_j$ for $i=1,2.,,,.m, j = 1,2,...n$. As $X$ is infinite, there exists $z \in X$ with $z \not \in X \setminus U_x$ and $z \not\in X \setminus U_y$ and thus $z \in U_x \cap U_y$ thus $U_x,U_y$ are non disjoint thus $(X,\tau)$ is non-Hausdorff.

For compact, let $\{U_a\}_{a \in A}$, $A$ some arbitrary indexing set be an open cover for $X$. Fix some $b \in A$ and then

$$X \setminus U_b=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}.$$

I.e., $X \setminus U_b$ is a finite set, so for $x_j \in X \setminus U_b$, let $U_j$ be the open set containing $x_j$, then

$$U_b \cup \bigcup_{j=1}^k U_j$$

is a finite subcover for $X$ thus $(X,\tau)$ is compact.

**Added** this example fails
To not be locally compact, but rather is an example of a compact non-Hausdorff space for any future reference.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked, since this space is locally compact: in fact, every subspace of this space is compact.

Comment: @StevenClontz oops I just read the main title and came up with the example which is compact and non-Hausdorff.

Comment: Good point, I've edited the title for clarity.

Comment: And I’ve edited my answer in case anyone needs an example such as mine in the future. @StevenClontz